# Extension Methode doesn't appear after entity instance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework-4

I have a WPF project. I create an entity model. When I create an instance from that model.

I press "." after it to use extension methods like "select , where ,..."

That methods didn't appear after the instance

I found the following methods

this is the code :

```
 GazEntity Context = new GazEntity();
        private ObservableCollection<GasPapers> _papers;
        public RegisterPaper()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

    // here is the problem 
            Context.GasPapers .
    // I didn't see any   extension methods  after period 
}
```

}

Comment: Well those are usually used for *collections*, not single items... could you give an example of what's not working and what you expected it to do?

Comment: Can you show the code of your extension method?

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - seriously - do you think *anyone* can answer this, if you re-read your question? You're not showing us ***anything*** - not a single line of code - how are we supposed to know what's wrong????

Comment: Have you added System.Linq to your usings?

Comment: Extension methods for IEnumerable are defined on the static class called Enumerable which is in the System.Linq namespace. If you are not getting the extension methods like select where, then the most probable cause is that you have not got the namespace System.Linq included in the project.

Comment: I am sorry for my bad question , but I  couldn't post  images about problem , because of low reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a using for `System.Linq`. So add the following line at the top of the code file:

```
using System.Linq;
```